# How to dynamically define the views folder for desktop and mobile views

Tags: laravel

Basically, I have a directory like this:

```
├── views
|   ├── mobile
|   |   ├── main.blade.php
|   └── desktop
|       ├── main.blade.php
```

I have jenssegers/agent so I can detect whether the user is using a mobile/desktop, and then dynamically load the /mobile or /desktop views.

I've got an AgentServiceProvider which detects if it is mobile or not, and I can pass it to the views, but I don't know how to modify the directory dynamically.

I know the path is statically loaded inside the view.php file:

```
'paths' => [
    resource_path('views'),
],
```

How can I set up the views directory to views/desktop and views/mobile dynamically?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just set the view to render from the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically update the config for the current Request, e.g. in the AgentServiceProvider:

```
config([' view.paths' => resource_path('views/mobile')]);
```

The value would be dynamic based on the result of the package, e.g.

```
$path = $agent->isMobile() ? 'views/mobile' : 'views/desktop';
config([' view.paths' => resource_path($path)]);
```